# Rotation of a Curve

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing, curves, rotations

In an Analytical Mechanics text I have read that, given a regular plane curve $\gamma(t): ]a,b[ \to \Bbb R^2$, if $\underline{t}(s)$ is the tangent vector wrt to the natural parameter $s$, then the curve obtained by integrating $(\underline{t}(s) + \underline{c})$, where $\underline{c}$ is a constant in $\Bbb R^2$, is just a rotated $\gamma$ (by rotation I mean that there exists a matrix $R \in SO(2)$ such it transforms $\gamma$ in the integrated curve).

Does anyone know how to prove such claim?

---

As always, any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer.

Comment: I am having trouble to understand this. When we integrate $(\underline{t}(s) + \underline{c})$ we should get $\gamma(s)+\underline{c}s$. A rotation of $\gamma(s)$ preserves the length of this vector. The $s$-dependent translation that we get does not do that.

Comment: @KurtG. I know that it seems a little bit off. In the text is written that after integrating a second order ODE in $\underline{t}$ "we obtain $d\underline{t}/ds$ up to a constant (i.e.: rotation of the curve)"

Comment: What you’ve written is wrong. You integrate the unit tangent vector and you recover the original curve up to a translation. There is no rotational ambiguity.

Comment: @TedShifrin But what if I integrate say $d^2 \underline{t} / ds^2$ before integrating the unit tangent vector?

Comment: A second order ODE in $\underline{t}$ is a third order ODE in $\gamma$. Integrating reduces the order by one and adds a constant - as we know. Nonetheless, it is probably time to give a reference to this Analytical Mechanics text or more background from that.

Comment: This sounds like it’s supposed to be the Fundamental Theorem of Curve Theory: Knowing the curvature of a plane curve determines it uniquely up a rigid motion — translation and rotation. You can find the more general version for space curves in any differential geometry text.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: @KurtG. The text is "Analytical Mechanics" by Fasano and Marmi

Comment: Nice book. They provide the Fundamental Theorem of Curve Theory on p. 11 where they mention translations and rotations.

Comment: @KurtG. Exactly, however, I do not understand the part of the proof in which it mentions rotations.

Comment: @TedShifrin . As you say, the more general version for space curves is easy to find. Nonetheless, what do you think about the 2D case as being handled in the book (see also my answer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their proof of the *Fundamental Theorem of Curve Theory* the authors of [1] start with the following second order ODE for the tangent vector $\mathbf{t}$ w.r.t. the natural parametrization $s$:
$$\tag{1.17}
\frac{\rm{d}^2\mathbf{t}}{\rm{d}s^2}-\frac{k'(s)}{k(s)}\frac{\rm{d}\mathbf{t}}{\rm{d}s}+k^2(s)\mathbf{t}=0\,;
$$
where $k(s)>0$. They write "after integration this yields $\mathbf{t}=\rm{d}\mathbf{x}/\rm{d}s$ up to a constant vector (i.e. a rotation of the curve)."

I find that a bit odd. What I can understand is that (1.17) is a linear ODE that determines the solution $\mathbf{t}$ only up to an affine transformation. Since in the natural parametrization the tangent vector $\mathbf{t}$ always has length one the only
possible affine transformations that preserve the length of $\mathbf{t}$ are rotations or reflections, i.e., matrices in $O(2)$.

Clearly these matrices act on $\mathbf{x}$ (the curve itself) in the same way
as they act on the tangent vectors $\mathbf{t}$.

[1] A. Fasano, S. Marmi, *Analytical Mechanics.* Oxford 2006.

Comment: “Up to a constant vector” is just wrong. They mean up to multiplication by an element of $SO(2)$ (a reflection will change the sign of the signed curvature). When you say affine transformation, I disagree. You cannot translate $\mathbf t$ here. Maybe it’s better to phrase this as an initial value problem to clarify matters.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. For example, let us consider $\underline{c}=(-1,0)$ and $\gamma(t)=(t,0)$ (a line): then
$$\underline{t}(s)+\underline c=0$$
and so the curve obtained by integrating is actually a point (i.e. a constant curve)!

So in general the curve is not transformed by a rotation, or by a bijective map.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the clear example! :)